# Pass data programatically on route change with React router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

Requirement is to pass certain data to a component which will get rendered on a route change (programatically). Current I am using push from 'react-router-redux' without passing any data.

So I am navigating to /Animal and passing particular animals detail in data I want URl to show http://localhost/Animal

I am using React router 4.

```
import {push} from 'react-router-redux';

export function changeRoute(newRoute, data) {
    return (dispatch) => dispatch(push(newroute));
}
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Why don't  you just use the `<Redirect>` component, as you can specify the url with parameters?

Comment: I don't want url to show those parameters, also I need it to be done on a button click.

Comment: ok, but you didn't state that as a requirement. You could still use the redirect component and store the data in redux

Comment: But is it advisable for one page to directly change state of another component which is not even yet loaded.

Comment: No it can't change the state yet anyway, my suggestion is like what @palsrealm has suggested, to store the data in redux, redirect to the Animal component, which then retrieves the data it is expecting

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the data using an action from your page and retrieve it using the appropriate reducer from the Animal page.

```
animalActions.setData(data);
animalActions.changeRoute(newRoute);
```

In in the Animal page,

```
mapStateToProps =(state)=>{
    return{
     animalData:animalReducer.data
          }
}
```

Then you can access the data using props.

Comment: I'm sorry if my answer was not useful. Guess i did not understand the question. My apologies.

Comment: thanks for answering, but am just wondering if we can't set state in the location attribute of router and then access it from there? Something like one mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173786/react-router-pass-data-when-navigating-programatically? Is it available in react router 4