# How to pass a variable between web pages when using Reactjs Router Switch to navigate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router, parameter-passing

I am working on a web application that can load one of several scenarios based on a selection that a user makes.

A webpage has already been implemented to load a scenario, which is initiated by making an API call to the back end (python via flask).

The web-based UI is in javascript making use of react js.

At the moment I use the Router Switch method to allow navigation between a few web pages.

What I would like to achieve is:

1. On Home page, user selects scenario and presses Load
2. Load in fact calls a `renderRedirect()` function, and triggers navigation to the Scenario page.
3. Upon arrival on the Scenario page, the API call to the back-end is made  requesting the creation of the specific scenario that the user had selected in step 1.

What I don't know is how to get the information (just a string `scenario_id`) from the Home page to the Scenario page.

I found [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173786/react-router-pass-data-when-), but to implement it I would have to rework my current `Switch` setup to instead make use of `router.push`, unless I am mistaken?

Here is my current Routing code:

```
render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/new-scenario' component={NewScenario}/>
            <Route exact path='/about' component={About}/>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Please post the relevant switch/route code.  Is the redirect a total page load or a route change? What version of React Router is this?

Comment: @AlexW , ok: did that, it's the latest version (that's what it says in my packages - not sure how to check the version number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you only want the scenario_id, I think you can do it via url params

if you select scenario_id 1 on home page your url can be something like
/scenario/1

so you could define your route like this

```
       <Route exact path="/scenario/:id" render={props => <ScenarioComponent {...props} /> } />
```

with this code you're sending the :id part of the url to your component via props
you can get the value on Scenario with

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

Comment: Thanks! Testing this now. How would that URL look in the browser. Assume the id is "demo_sc", then the URL would be  ".../scenario/:demo_sc"  ?  ".../scenario/id:demo_sc" ?   ".../scenario/demo_sc" ?

Comment: the answer to the above question is the the third option `.../scenario/demo_sc`. Thanks so much for the help!