# React pass object by routing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap, react-router-dom

What I want to do is set routing to my object. For example:

I set routing for:

```
http://localhost:3000/projects
```

It displays all my projects list (it works pretty ok)

Then I want to choose project and see details, but it doesn't work properly:

```
http://localhost:3000/projects/3
```

How it looks like:

[image: View of my projects list]

When I click to `Details` button, it sends me to `/projects:id` but I get an error, that items in `project` are undefined.

My code. I store all routing in main **`App.js`** file:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Route exact path="/projects" component={ProjectsList} />
            <Route exact path="/projects/:id" component={ProjectDetails} />
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have `ProjectsList.js` component (i will include code of it if needed), in `ProjectsList.js` i have listgroup with **`Project.js`** that looks like this:

```
class Project extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ButtonToolbar>
        <ListGroupItem>{this.props.project.name</ListGroupItem>
        <Link to={`/projects/${this.props.project.id}`}>
          <Button>Details</Button>
        </Link>
      </ButtonToolbar>
    );
  }
}
export default Project;
```

By `Link to` my browser pass me to proper URL (`projects/2...` etc) but i dont know how to pass object of `project` to **`ProjectDetails.js`** component. Code of it below:

```
class ProjectDetails extends Component {
  render() {
    return <li>{this.props.project.description}</li>;
  }
}
export default ProjectDetails;
```

Could you tell me, how to pass object of `project` by `Link to` into `ProjectDetails.js`? For now, i get `description` as undefined (its obviouse because i pass nothing to component with details).

Comment: i get a downvote, it would be nice if i could know, for what?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React router, pass data when navigating programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173786/react-router-pass-data-when-navigating-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the render method in your route and pass the props.

```
   <Route exact path="/projects/:id" render={() => (
         <ProjectDetails
         project = {project}
         />
   )}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `mapStateToProps` here. and wrap your component in the `conncet` from `react-redux`.

It should be like:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class ProjectDetails extends Component {
  render() {
    return <li>{this.props.project.description}</li>;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
   const projectInstance = DATA //the Data you are getting or fetching from the ID.
   return { project : projectInstance }
}

export default connect((mapStateToProps)(ProjectDetails))
```

Comment: But how `Project.js` should looks like to get that DATA u mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

This is what it will look like..!!

```
class Project extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ButtonToolbar>
        <ListGroupItem>{this.props.project.name</ListGroupItem>
        <Link to={`/projects/${this.props.project.id}`}>
          <Button>Details</Button>
        </Link>
      </ButtonToolbar>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
   return { project : { id: ownProps.params.id } }
}

export default connect((mapStateToProps)(Project))
```