# How to pass a hook state from one component to another in a axios function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I'm trying to pass a hook state to another component inside the Axios function.
The state has the initial value to false, but when the method post happens to Axios, inside then()
I made the state to true which in this case is `setShowFlagCreate(true)`
Im trying to pass this state to the UserList.js component, but I don't know-how.
After I pass it, I wanna use this state to show the flag(which says a user has been created.) on the UserList.js page

How can I do this?

UserCreate.js

```
export default function UserCreate({}) {

const [showFlagCreate, setShowFlagCreate] = useState(false)

const save = async () => {

    const UserParams = {
      userName:
        currentUser
      Gender: gender,
      country: USA,
    };
 
    await axios
      .post(
        process.env.REACT_APP_URL, userParams
      )  
      .then((response) => {
        navigate("/userlist");
        setShowFlag(true); //I want this state to pass it on the UserList component as true
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  

    };
}
return(
  <div>
  </div>
)
```

UserList.js

```
export default function UserList() {

  const [showFlagCreate, setShowFlagCreate] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(process.env.REACT_API_URL + usersParams) //geting the user form db
      .then((response) => {
        response.data.forEach(function (item) {
          let newUser = {
            id: user.id,
            name: Username,
            gender: "male",
            description: "stuff",
          };
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
        <FlagCreate show={showFlagCreate} setShow={setShowFlagCreate}/> //passing the props
     </div>
);
}
```

I want to get the state in UserList component and show the flag since the state is true.

```
FlagCreat.js

export default function FlagCreate({ show, setShow }) {
 <div>
     <div>
        <p>The user that you have been created is saved.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => {setShow(false)}}>
          <span >Close</span>
      </button>               
 </div>
}
```

The idea is that after the setShowFlagCreate turned to true in UserCreate.js , the flag has to be shown in the UserCreate component . How can I make it work?

Comment: What navigation library are you using?

Comment: @Vencovsky this ```import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";```

Comment: If on a successful response you always navigate to UserList component, you can just provide a query parameter with the value and you won't even need to use state here. Navigate like this `navigate("/userlist?showFlagCreate=true");` and then read the value of query param inside UserList component

Comment: And when you want to set the `show` to false you can simply remove the query param from the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is pass the state when calling `navigation` retrieve that state in the `UserList`.

UserCreate

```js
navigate("/userlist", { state: { showFlag: true } });
```

UserList

```
const { state } = useLocation();
const { showFlag } = state; // use showFlag the way you want.
```

You can understand more how it works with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52138179/9119186)

Answer (score 0):

you could define this state in contextApi and share it everywhere you need -
[you can read about it here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)