# I can not get data via state with ReactJS navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to find a solution for states in ReactJS. I am using ReactJS v18.2 and react-router-dom library for navigation. I have the following code block for login page.

```
    async function handleLogin() {
    Auth.signIn(userInformation.name!, userInformation.password)
        .then((user) => {
            if (user.challengeName === 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED') {
                navigate('/auth/forgetPassword', { state: { user: user } })
            } else {               
                navigate('/main', { state: { user: user } })
            }
        })
        .catch((_) => {
            setErrorMessage(t('Wrong credentials!'))
        })
}
```

I am trying to fetch data of the user with navigation and redirect to forgot password screen with the state data as in below.

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Button, TextField, Typography, Box, FormGroup } from '@mui/material'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'
import { User } from '../configs/types/Users'
import { uniqueId } from '../utils'
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'

export default function ForgetPassword() {
 const { t } = useTranslation()
 const location = useLocation()
 const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState<string>('')
 const [userInformation, setUserInformation] = useState<Partial<User>>({
    password: '',
    passwordRepeat: '',
    givenName: '',
    familyName: '',
})

console.log(location)
//rest of the codeblock
```

When I print the result in forgot password state, following location results are as follow:

```
  {
   pathname: '/auth/forgetPassword',
   search: '',
   hash: '',
   state: null,
   key: 'default'
  }
```

As seen above, state is always returning null value. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How do you print those results?

Comment: It seems like there is no error, but you can explore this answer and can re-check your code accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52138179/21957513

Comment: @Geshode via console.log

Comment: @MaulikPatel I have already implemented the code as in the link but still state is returning null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. It is related to data that is stored in state. It was an object and I have just converted the data into string and it worked.